# svg vs canvas for SEO

Tags: seo, html, semantic-web, svg, canvas

While choosing a charting library for my react application, one of the criteria that I am evaluating is whether the library works with canvas or svg internally. Apart from the various other factors like ease of use, developer convenience, flexibility, learning curve, I am also trying to evaluate the SEO benefits of using one vs other.

Practically speaking, should data visualizations be considered for SEO at all, or should we have some alternative representation for SEO?

If data visualizations should be a candidate for SEO, do search engine recognize and index svg elements? I know that google indexes svg images, but couldn't find any information about svg elements is general. Another thing that I kinda understand is svg elements are part of the DOM, so the text they contain can still be indexed as compared to canvas, which is devoid of any semantics.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: See also: [Do search engines index text contained in SVG elements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/do-search-engines-index-text-contained-in-svg-elements)   and [Can text content in an HTML5 <canvas> element be indexed by search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/900/can-text-content-in-an-html5-canvas-element-be-indexed-by-search-engines)

Comment: How much text are on these data visualization?  Is it paragraphs, a couple sentences, just labels on a graph, or no text?

Comment: These are line series charts, which show dynamic tooltip on interactions which shows the data for that particular point. Then there are the axes which display the domain and range.

Comment: so, not a lot of static text, apart from the labels of the line series, but a lot of data, should that data be indexed at all ? should it be searchable ?